# What are the upgrade paths to Elementary OS 5.0?

Tags: release-loki, updates, release-juno

If I want to install Elementary OS now and upgrade to 5.0 when it is released, should I install Elementary OS 0.4.1 or 5.0 beta? Can either/both upgrade to 5.0?

Comment: it depends. do you have Loki installed on your device or not ?
your question it doesn't seems clear

Comment: At the time of asking I didn't have any version of Elementary OS installed yet.

Comment: so you are free to install 5.0 Juno, u don't have to install the 0.4.1 or Loki first... Happy FWUL (Forget Windows Use Linux) ;)

Comment: Juno is not released yet. I'm asking if I could install Juno beta and upgrade to Juno later, or install Loki and upgrade to Juno later.